# Passing Variables through Views in Django Template

Tags: python, django, view, django-templates, arguments

Trying to figure out how to access my variables in Django templating system. My models.py:

```
class SubCategory(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
   category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

My view:

```
from myapp.models import Category, SubCategory

def create_in_category(request, slug):
   category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug)
   subcategory = SubCategory()

   ad = Ad.objects.create(category=category, subcategory=subcategory, user=request.user,
                       expires_on=datetime.datetime.now(), active=False)
   ad.save()
   return redirect('myapp_create_ad_edit', pk=ad.pk)
...

class AdCreationEditView(AdEditView):
   def get_queryset(self):
       qs = super(AdEditView, self).get_queryset()
       return qs.filter(active=False, user=self.request.user)

   def get_success_url(self):
       return reverse('classifieds_create_ad_preview',
                      kwargs=dict(pk=self.object.pk))

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super(AdCreationEditView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context['create'] = True
       return context
```

---

I want to be able to access `{{ subcategory }}` in my template, but resulting in an error: `'subcategory' is an invalid keyword argument for this function` because of error in my view. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Where are you using a template? I don't see any template rendering going on here.

Comment: What's actually *rendering* that template, though? The function you listed just redirects, it doesn't render anything.

Comment: That isn't the view where you render the template. You're redirecting, not rendering.

Answer (score 0):

That error isn't coming from your template, and has nothing whatsoever to do with your question. `subcategory` is a ManyToMany relationship, and you can't define those on object instantiation because of the way such a relationship is implemented via linking table - you need to save both the Category and Subcategory objects first.

The answer to your actual question on how to pass objects to the template is fully answered in the tutorial.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes I have read the tutorial multiple times and the djangobook. While I have read the documentation, I do not fully comprehend how to apply it to my scenario, which is why I was hoping for another set of eyes. I have tried to use access `subcategory = get_list_or_404(Subcategory)`, but still not sure how to properly define the elements inside of my view. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: I don't really know how to answer you. You have two major problems: firstly, the error message, which is preventing you from creating the category/subcategory objects in the first place; and secondly, confusion about how to pass stuff to the template. You should first demonstrate that you've fixed the first one, then maybe we can clear up any remaining confusion about templates.